# When do you use "s" apostrophe to refer to authors ($e.g.$ of inequalities)?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing

I remarked that there does not seem to be a general rule whether one should use or not an "s" apostrophe for inequalities For example, we can encounter Hölder's inequality, but Minkowski or Sobolev inequality, Cauchy's inequality, but Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, etc. There seems however to be a rule to remove the "s" when there is more than one person referred to in the inequality, but the first example suggests that for simple names, the general rule is not obvious, if there is any. The same question could be addressed to for theorems, identities, or laws, but I do not know an example contradicting the $\textit{a priori}$ rule : one name, use "s", two or more names, do not use "s".

Comment: I fear this is a duplicate of some other question. As a rule, I'd say "The Cauchy inequality" or "Cauchy's inequality", but I'm no native speaker.

Comment: Several of the examples mentioned in this question are grammatically incorrect. As it stands, this does not seem related to math, but simply to English grammar (it should for example be *the* Cauchy-Schwartz inequality).

Comment: One also finds 'Hölder inequality' and "Minkowski's  inequality."  In my understanding it is also not  about removing the s, but the one expresses possession (to whom the inequality "belongs" that is who established it), while in the other case it is a name for some result (and it is used with a definite article).  So the Name Thing can only be used for established things.  More than one name rarely if ever having the  s construction is I think mainly due to the alternative being clunky. If in that case one wants to express possession to resort to "of name1 and name2" is an option.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Nevertheless, Wikipedia uses "Poincare duality" without "the".

Comment: I'd say you may find a better answer in http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev That is because "duality" is a concept. One can also just refer to "by duality", whereas it is not possible to just say "by inequality".

Comment: Should I delete the post?

Comment: I'd leave it around for a while (a day) to see what happens.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: It should be the Cauchy-Schwarz (not Schwartz) inequality.